# Do all apps lose state when the phone is locked?

Tags: wi-fi, lock-screens

I use Rune for music. It takes Rune a bit of time to find its controller on the network. If, after starting some music playing, I then lock the phone, when I come back Rune starts all over to locate its controller. I had a similar experience with Sony's 'imaging edge' app for remote-controlling my camera. As soon the phone locked, I had to go through the elaborate connection process all over again.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: An app loses it's state if it is killed. This can happen if the Android OS is running out of RAM or on some devices this may also happen by a very aggressive battery saving feature.

Comment: There's no shortage of memory. On my moto g7, perhaps I've made an bad setting choice for battery saving.

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com